# Phonegap app cannot instantiate module myApp

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting this unhelpful error:

Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
{1}

Can someone please take a look at this jsfiddle and let me know if they see the issue?

http://jsfiddle.net/9Yf5V/

I also have a controller and factory set up, but I doubt it's even getting to that point and causing the issue. Just in case, here is controller code:

```
function mainControl($scope , $http , $log ,  facebook){
$scope.test = function(){
    facebook.getLoginStatus();
    $scope.apply();
}

$scope.console = function(){
    $scope.$log = $log;
    $scope.message = 'heeyyy!';
}
}
```

and here is factory code:

```
myApp.factory('facebook' , ['$window' , function($window){
var FB = $window.FB;

if(!FB) throw new error ('Facebook not loaded');

FB.init ({
    appId: "443530475777959",
    nativeInterface: CDV.FB,
    useCachedDialogs: false
});

return{
    getLoginStatus: function(){
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
            console.log(response);
        })
    }
}

}])
```

Any help as well as an explanation of why myApp is not loading would be great appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Where is `CDV` being defined?

Comment: I think CDV is defined in the facebook SDK. I'm moving old code into a new app so I haven't included the SDK yet, but do you think that could be what's stopping myApp from loading? Is the html structured correctly for including angular?

Comment: I just tried including the SDK and I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at the JSfiddle a few things pop out:

1) `templateUrl` defines the page to load in the place of the object you're using it on. so calling `templateUrl: '\'` causes a recursive loop pretty much.

2) `controller: mainControl` needs to be `controller: 'mainControl'` most refrences in angular are strings.

3) `when` is a method of `$routeProvider` so you can't just call it out of nowhere, typically you call `$routeProvider.when()` and you can chain off of that if you like.

Forked Fiddle for convienience. I've removed bits that fiddle doesn't like, and commented out your script block, adding angular-route through the external resources tab of Fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/7T82h/

I suspect your app can't call your controller, which would throw that error I believe.

Comment: I think it was the templateUrl and controller that was causing the issue. It got rid of the error. Thank you very much. Can I just put templateUrl: 'index.html'? index.html has the html and js/controllers has the $routeProvider.

Comment: templateUrl should have any controller specific HTML that you want loaded into the element. So if its index.html, it will load that, which may be recursive if index.html calls the controller again. Typically you have `ng-view` in index.html, and you call the actual content in a separate file that will be loaded into the element hat has `ng-view`